# Linux make return + <key> = ctrl-<key>

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping

I want my return key to act like normal return when pressed alone, but act like control (ctrl) when pressed with another key.

Example: Pressing  + c = ctrl-c

What tools would I use to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not practical.

(1) There is no logic in the keyboard driver to make a key dual purpose like you want.
A key is either a modifier or it generates a character.
A key cannot do both functions.

(2) The normal response of the `Enter` key would have to be radically changed to function as you describe.
Normally as soon as you press the `Enter` key, the keystroke for a return character is registered, displayed, and acted on.
All that happens before the `Enter` key is released, and before any other key press that you want to combine.

So in your scheme, what should the keyboard driver do when the `Enter` key is pressed?
Should it wait for another key to be pressed or generate the return character?
Any delay in generating the return character will probably confuse the user.

Alternate solution: Use the `Ctrl` key.